# Programming Languages recommended for work in mathematics and to understand computational complexity

Tags: soft-question, computer-science, computational-complexity, math-software, advice

I am an undergraduate mathematics student and I am managing to stay a semester ahead of my classes. One way in which I want to use my free time is to learn a computer language(s) that will help me in my mathematical future as someone who wants to work in pure mathematics. Also I am interested in algorithms and complexity theory and classes. I have no background in any language as of now

*Question: Which language or set of languages are usually taught to develop a base understanding for programming that also are used by the working mathematicians today? And which set of languages are more oriented towards algorithmic and complexity theory? Is there any intersection between the two?*

Thanks in advance guys/gals. Any comment,answer or input is appreciated!!

Comment: The C language, if you understand it the rest will be easy.

Comment: Now if (after say 2 weeks) you don't understand what the C language is about, try python or java or javascript or matlab.

Comment: @user1952009 I did start learning C some years back although didn't stick with it. I have been told that it is an outmoded language. Are you suggesting it as merely a language to build a strong foundation or does it still have utility with respect to math and more general uses??

Comment: It is the language you need to learn if you want to understand the rest, and most libraries and softwares are programmed in C/C++ so you need it for modifying and understanding them. But if you are not good enough, try another language, and come back to the C later (and the people criticizing the C are just not good enough, or are affraid that you are not good enough).

Comment: I would recommend C++. It's easier to learn than C since it's object oriented.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Come on.. Did you learn the C and C++ ? Would you say that `std::string` is easier to understand than `strcat` and `strlen` ?

Comment: To a mathematician, I would recommend [Sage](http://sagemath.org). And I am not unfamiliar with other languages, but I think a combination of Python and Sage would fit best.

Comment: @user1952009 In this case actually yes. But nonetheless, C++ is far more complicated than C.

Comment: @deviantfan Yes C++ can be complicated, and the best proof is to take a look at the source code of `std::string` .. On the other hand, the source code for the standard C library is trivial (and take in account that you use a IDE and a debugger when programming in C, so it often happens you have to step in the standard library source code)

Comment: @user1952009 I didn't mean the source etc. . But eg. explaining to a beginner what a terminating \0 is, when the program crashes because of a too small array, is imho more complicated that showing them `s3 = s1 + s2;` ... But, as said, it doesn't change that C++ is a hard language.

Comment: @deviantfan I think you don't understand that it's the point of the C language :  of course writing 3 loops with an array and 2 functions is harder  in C than python or java, that's the point !! Understanding how it works !! It is exactly the same in maths when you are proving a theorem for understanding in details what is happening.

Comment: And by the way, if you want to focus on _computational complexity_, I think the book [Numerical Recipes in C](http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php) is a really good start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For an introduction into programming I would recommend a "script language":

- Modern script languages (e.g. Python, Ruby) tend to be not the most efficient in hardware usage, but are expressive and great for developing complex programs. Ruby is more
  elegant than Python IMHO, but Python has lots of great mathematical
  libraries. So Python would be a good choice.

Then there are the languages which allow one to write fast programs, programs that utilize memory very efficiently and can talk to most hardware:

- The general purpose languages that allow you to use the hardware very
  efficiently usually lack in abstraction and have only simple data
  structures. (C, FORTRAN)
- C++ with modern libraries is hardware efficient and has advanced data
  structures.

Sometimes easy portability to different operating systems and hardware is   important:

- Java has the advantage of being quite portable, including its graphical user interface, but is not that expressive compared to modern script languages and used to be no language that uses the hardware efficiently. However that might have changed due to compiler and VM optimizations. E.g. GeoGebra is a mathematics software that is implemented in Java, because of these advantages. Java is probably the most mainstream language today. (E.g. see [this ranking](http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/)).

There are languages which focus on mathematics:

- Mathematica, Maple, Matlab or R are examples. Each has its strengths.
- Julia seems
  to be a promising new language, but I have no experience with it.

Then the occasional surprise:

- JavaScript. As native language of the web browser it
  became more and more important over the years. It is an unlikely
  recommendation regarding mathematics right now, but it might continue to surprise.

Finally you might want to broaden your understanding of programming:

- The languages above usually follow the imperative programming paradigm,
  as structured or object oriented languages.
  However there are alternative approaches to programming, like
- declarative programming, e.g. Prolog or
- functional programming (e.g. Lisp, Haskell, Erlang, OCaml, F#).

They excel for certain problems and widen the understanding of programming. Their ideas have connections to logic and theory of computation.

Comment: I actually use Javascript to do quick mathematical computations as it is far easier to do stuff in it than in Python or Java, but one must note that there are about as many crazy rules (pitfalls) as there are intuitive rules. I was utterly struck when I first realized `""==0` ridiculously returns `true`!

Answer (score 15):

I agree with @Pieter21 that python is your best bet now for general usefulness as a math major, and later on in advanced work in pure mathematics.

For a striking (mind-bending) overview of computation, I strongly recommend Abelson and Sussman's [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://web.mit.edu/alexmv/6.037/sicp.pdf). You're not likely to use Scheme (a dialect of Lisp) for actual programming projects, but the philosophical content of the book is enlightening.

I don't know of any language that would be particularly useful for thinking about complexity theory.

I think learning C would be a mistake - lots of up front cost before you get to the parts that you care about.

Comment: In my opinion "*I don't know of any language that would be particularly useful for thinking about complexity theory*" is a proof that you don't know the C language.

Comment: @user1952009 I know C, and have taught it. I don't think the OP would find its low abstraction level useful for thinking about complexity. If he or she really wanted a  language for reasoning about complexity at its bare bones I'd recommend Knuth's mmix: http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/mmix.html . I hesitated to make that part of my answer; it's pretty specialized.

Comment: Since ~1990 the way to learn an assembly language is with the inline assembler in C.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for your input. I've been looking at Knuth's Art of Computer Programming you provided a link to. I have taken mathematical logic and the preliminaries chapter covers stuff much of which I am already familiar with. It seems like a very approachable and self contained book at first glance on understanding algorithms in a general sense. Am I wrong about this? Would you say it's readable without knowing a progamming language and much about computer science??

Comment: SICP always justifies +1 to the question. Also Python is not bad in general and it has got some good libraries for maths like Sympy.

Comment: C and C++ are bad not because of additional front cost, but because you will be constantly exposing yourself to undefined behavior and it's just too bad thing to tolerate unless the goal is to write extremely optimized code. Even the most clever and experienced people write buggy and vulnerable code in these languages, this is fact of life.

Comment: At my university, one of the mandatory first semester courses for mathematics is about C++. And it's generally considered by the students to be the easiest one in the semester. I like Python very much, personally, but I think C/C++ is also useful to know and not unreasonable to learn early.

Comment: I would actually disagree about learning C/C++ in order to understand complexity: The languages are so low-level that the nitty-gritty of implementation occludes the actual algorithmic complexity of the stuff you're trying to implement (number of CPU operations is *not* equivalent to complexity); In other words, you can't see the forest for the trees. A higher-language language like Python or Ruby facilitates reasoning about algorithms while still allowing you to "imagine" how the code is translated into CPU instructions when you want to look more deeply.

Comment: @Red I've used Knuth only as an occasional reference, so can't help you with how readable it is given your background. Knuth writes well, which always helps a lot. Give it a try. Abelson and Sussman write well too - sometimes that book reads like a novel. If your logic course got to the lambda calculus you'll have a head start.There are many online scheme interpreters you can play with.

Answer (score 6):

For your specific question, a language suited to mathematicians and to understanding computational complexity, I recommend a functional programming language, in particular Haskell or Scheme.

[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) is a very elegant yet also practical functional programming. Inspired my mathematical notation, it has a very strong type system and a declarative style, reminiscent of mathematical reasoning. In specific with regards to your point of intersection between "a programming language for mathematicians" and "a programming language to understand computational complexity better", I would most strongly recommend Haskell.

Scheme is a dialect of Lisp, one of the oldest languages in existence today, which is inspired on $\lambda$-calculus. Very minimalist, very elegant, and I will almost guarantee you that understanding it will make you a better programmer and a better mathematician. If you want go down this route I recommend following [The Little Schemer](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/little-schemer), an absolutely delightful book by Daniel P. Friedman and Matthias Felleisen.

Comment: I agree that Haskell is THE language a mathematician should learn... I disagree that it is particularly useful to "understand computational complexity" (quite the opposite imho).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to do, I would recommend different languages.

#### For understanding computational complexity and basic algorithms, **python** or **C**.

Python is beginner friendly, and have much better readability than C++ or Java. It's easy to write very clean algorithms with it's clean syntax. It's suitable for your first programming language.

For example, to exchange two integers:

In python:

```
x, y = y, x
```

In C/C++/Java

```
int t = x; x = y; y = t;
```

C is much older than python, however C is a simple language, with only a few keywords and no advanced OOP constructs. It's also suitable for experimenting with simple algorithms.

C++ is a superset of C which mainly added features for software engineering purpose. If you want to dig deeper into CS from a technical point, C++ or Java is also recommanded.

#### For learning pure mathematics, Wolfram Language (or widely known as Mathematica) is strongly recommended.

Mathematica was initially developed as a research tool for Mathematicians, however recently it introduced a lot of new functionalities on engineering and general computing.

Factor polynomials, solving differential equations, finding huge eigenvalues, simulating quantum effects, proving simple theorems, making interactive graphics ... you won't find many software can do all these at once. It's a symbolic programming language, which means it can handle exact mathematical expressions instead of just a numerical expression.

```
In[1]:= Integrate[ Sin[x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]                                                                                                                          

             Pi
        Sqrt[--]
             2
Out[1]= --------
           2
```

It would require a lot effort to code that in C or python without external package.

Mathematica also features some syntax for functional programming so you can experiment with different programming paradigms.

#### For engineering oriented, python, matlab, R is recommended.

Mathematica is a bit short on Engineering because its slower execution and the only double precision support for dense matrices.

Yeah, I mentioned python again, because people have developed countless tools for numerical related usage.

- `numpy`: a general array utility, for vectors, matrices, or higher order tensors
- `scipy`: The sister of `numpy`, more useful tools and utilities for linear algebra, signal processing, statistics, image processing, and more ...
- `matplotlib`: Plot scientific graphics
- pandas, scikit-learn, sympy ... and more

MATLAB is developed from ground up for engineering purpose. (It's called *MAT*-LAB, which means it deal with numerical matrices) It has more dedicated tools for very specific tasks. I'm not a matlab user, so I can't give more info.

R is developed for statistics and data science. It gained substantial popularity in recent years. I'm not an R user, so I can't give more info.

Answer (score 2):

As a second language for someone with a serious mathematical future, I might recommend [AMS $\LaTeX$](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex).

Much as being aware of category theory is useful, being aware of Haskell will be useful.

Comment: @MorganRodgers : Then you're not really *doing it*.  My $\LaTeX$ tends to be pages of programming followed by pages of text with markup and inclusions benefiting from the code in the first few pages.  Recall that $\LaTeX$ is Turing complete...

Answer (score 2):

I agree with andrepd. I suggest a functional programming language as well.

[Standard ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML) is a very clean language and most beautiful with mathematics. For example, here's how you can construct natural numbers with [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Addition)

```
datatype n = zero | s of n;

(* Addition *)
infix ADD
fun a ADD zero  = a |
    a ADD (s(b))= s(a ADD b);

(* Multiplication *)
infix MUL
fun a MUL zero  = zero |
    a MUL (s(b))= a ADD (a MUL b); 

val one = s(zero);
val two = s(s(zero));

one ADD two; (* s(s(s(zero))) which is 3 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have to recommend Python.

It should be easy enough to pick up the essentials, yet it has advanced mathmatical like features such as tuples, dictionaries.

And quite some interesting libraries that are easy to include, like itertools and numpy.

For instance, following python program solves the famous https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle:
(maybe not in the most efficient way, but I think very mathmatically, with permutations and combinations)

```
import itertools

N = 8

for p in itertools.permutations(range(N)):
    if all(abs(p[b]-p[a]) != (b-a) for a,b in itertools.combinations(range(N), 2)):
        print (p)
```

Comment: This is no way relates to what OP is asking, which is a language for the specific purpose of understanding computational complexity theory, which Python absolutely isn't suited to.

Answer (score 1):

**Python**: Consider [Python](https://www.python.org/). You may choose to start with simple projects, like a factoring program and a quadratic-equation solver. Thereafter you can create more complex projects once you’ve gotten the hang of things.From a mathematical and scientific standpoint probably the best part is the extensive amount of relevant libraries that are available

**Haskell**: Another programming language that is growing in popularity is [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/).  This [page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_and_mathematics) collects resources for using Haskell to do mathematics.Purely functional nature makes Haskell quite suitable for modeling mathematical problems.

**J**: The [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/) programming language is most suited to mathematical and statistical programming, especially if you intend to perform operations on matrices

**Coq**: [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) is basically a theorem prover. Coq works within the theory of the calculus of inductive constructions. It allows the expression of mathematical assertions, mechanically checks proofs of these assertions, helps to find formal proofs, and extracts a certified program from the constructive proof of its formal specification.